# Asking for time off for hospital procedure

Tags: time-off

A few weeks ago I took 2 days off holiday to have a PH test where they stick a tube in your nose for 24 attached to a small computer, but I was ill and it was cancelled. I have another one booked although it will only take 30mins I don't really want to go to work with a tube in my nose.

I don't want to take my last 2 days off for the year. Can I be reasonable and ask for a work from home and just take the few hours it will take for the procedure?

I've only been at this place for 5 months, though.

Comment: What country are you in?  The laws differ.

Answer (score 3):

Speak to you manager. Explain the situation. I am sure that they will have a little compassion and let you have the day off.

PS: you health is more important than any job.

Comment: Question isnt if they can get the day off. The question is if hey can not spend the remainder of their PTO on said day off.

Comment: Compassionate leave? Leave for medical reasons? In Europe this is common.

Comment: @EdHeal, many US companies no longer give sick leave, it is all lumped under Paid Time Off. If the OP has any days left for that, he will have to use them or go on leave without pay. He can ask to work from home, but if he is not already set up to do so, it might be difficult to get agreement.

Comment: Another good reason not to work in US IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the perfect opportunity to test the waters for their work from home philosophy.

If they say no though, dont be surprised and sorry you need to spend your last PTO on this.

Answer (score 0):

Medical tests sometimes qualify as sick time. Ask your manager and/or HR.